# how to pass random inputs from a input file to apache benchmark (abs) for load testing a URL

Tags: apache, testing, load-testing, apachebench

I want to pass random inputs for load testing my search URL .
Search texts have to be read from an Input file and appended in the URL and send for the AB load testing .

Eg. a) Input file :
        text1
        text2
        text3
    b) URL :- `{{BaseURL}}/apps/{{ApplId}}/courses/search?query={{random text from input file }}`

I would like to hit this search URL with different/random texts present in the input file .
Currently i am trying the below command which just takes one static URL :-

```
abs -n 100 -c 100 https://ib3rf43def /courses/search?query=course  > ../../abTestResult.txt
```

Thanks for the help in advance .!

Answer (score 1):

Use `siege` and `pwgen`, like this:

`siege -f <(pwgen -1 16 1024 | sed 's|^|example.com/?q=|')`